# Convert entire file from HEX to DEC in Batch, Python or VBS

Tags: batch-file

I have been researching for hours, but I cannot figure out how to convert a file "hex.txt" (with hex in it) to "dec.txt"(decimal).

Hex.txt has a bunch of hex values like this:

```
0x0000: 0a 00 00 08 00 06 61 75 74 68 6f 72 
0x000c: 00 09 41 6e 6f 6e 79 6d 6f 75 73 09 
0x0018: 00 06 62 6c 6f 63 6b 73 0a 00 00 01 
0x0024: 5a 09 00 03 70 6f 73 03 00 00 00 03
```

and I want to convert it to decimal with batch, vbs or python.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. Please paste here the code you have right now.

Comment: Are you able to make temporary files? `Certutil` can easily convert hex to ascii (and it's installed on every version of Windows after XP), but you'll need to remove everything from the start of the line to the colon first.

Comment: sebast26 I have been on here for over a year lol

Answer (score 3):

A batch solution (why other languages in title but no tags?).

- The command `set /A` will convert hex values to decimal if prefixed
  with `0x`
- So you need a `for /f`  to split the lines at the colon into address
  and values and another simple `for` to process each value.
- Setting and using values inside a (code block) requires
  [delayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

---

```
> type Hex2Dec.cmd
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in (hex.txt) Do (
    Set /A DecAddr=%%A
    Set "DecAddr=     !DecAddr!"
    Set "Dec="
    For %%C in (%%B) do (
        Set /A Dec#=0x%%C
        Set "Dec#=    !Dec#!"
        Set Dec=!Dec!!Dec#:~-4!
    )
    Echo !DecAddr:~-5!: !Dec!
)
```

Sample output:

```
> Hex2Dec.cmd
    0:   10   0   0   8   0   6  97 117 116 104 111 114
   12:    0   9  65 110 111 110 121 109 111 117 115   9
   24:    0   6  98 108 111  99 107 115  10   0   0   1
   36:   90   9   0   3 112 111 115   3   0   0   0   3
```

Comment: I think the OP actually wants hex to bin conversion. Though your answer is valid for the thing he requested.

Answer (score 3):

Why decimal? It is easy to turn each hex couple into decimal numbers ,but the hexadecimal format that you are showing looks like binary data (which I think is what you need)

```
@echo off

set "source=.\data.txt"

del /s /q /f .\temp.data
for /f "usebackq tokens=2,3 delims=:x" %%a  in ("%source%") do (
    rem (echo(%%a %%b)>>.\temp.data
    (echo(%%a %%b)>>.\temp.data
)

certutil -decodehex -f temp.data converted
```

Certutil can converd hexadecimal to binary though the format it is using is a little bit different no `:` and `x` so you'll need one temp file where they are purged.

Comment: Here binary output includes the addresses as binary data, echo only %%b to temp.data